# Convert Guava HashMultimap to json

Tags: json, gson, guava, multimap

I want to print HashMultiMap as json.

```
HashMultimap<String,Object> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
multimap.put("a",Obj1);
multimap.put("a",Obj3);
multimap.put("b",Obj2);
```

to

```
{ 
  "a":[Obj1,Obj3],
  "b":[Obj2]
}
```

Obj1 and other objects should again be in json(to keep it clean, I have shown it as objects)
I can iterate over the individual keys and convert set of Objects to json using libraries such as Gson.

But to get the entire snapshot of the HashMultimap, I want to convert it to json and inspect it.

Gson could not convert the entire map, but could do individual values(list of objects to json)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Call [`asMap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html#asMap()) on the MultiMap first. This converts the MultiMap to a standard Map where each value is a Collection.

In your example, the type of the resulting Map is `Map<String, Collection<Object>>`. Gson should be able to serialise this correctly.

Comment: Yep, checked this API after posting the question :) .Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @sat When you use the adapter, it all happens automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a `JsonAdapter` or both `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer`. It's rather terrible, but I wanted to try.

Basically, you delegate everything to a `Map<String, Collection<V>>`.

```
static class MultimapAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Multimap<String, ?>>, JsonSerializer<Multimap<String, ?>> {
    @Override public Multimap<String, ?> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        final HashMultimap<String, Object> result = HashMultimap.create();
        final Map<String, Collection<?>> map = context.deserialize(json, multimapTypeToMapType(type));
        for (final Map.Entry<String, ?> e : map.entrySet()) {
            final Collection<?> value = (Collection<?>) e.getValue();
            result.putAll(e.getKey(), value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override public JsonElement serialize(Multimap<String, ?> src, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final Map<?, ?> map = src.asMap();
        return context.serialize(map);
    }

    private <V> Type multimapTypeToMapType(Type type) {
        final Type[] typeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments();
        assert typeArguments.length == 2;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeToken<Map<String, Collection<V>>> mapTypeToken = new TypeToken<Map<String, Collection<V>>>() {}
        .where(new TypeParameter<V>() {}, (TypeToken<V>) TypeToken.of(typeArguments[1]));
        return mapTypeToken.getType();
    }
}
```

The full code including a test can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6wn4dmwwgih7bd/MultimapAdapterTest.java?dl=0).

Comment: Care to contribute the adapters to https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters? ([associated bug](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/526))

Comment: @dimo414 No time now, but feel free to do it. I guess, the SO license permits it already.

Comment: Is there any reasonable way to implement the `multimapTypeToMapType(Type type)` method without relying on Guava? Can you add the implementation (I know, wishful thinking, but does not hurt to ask) or  describe how it might be managed.

Comment: @GRosenberg I see my link was broken, fixed. Are you sure, you need a `Type` of a Guava class without relying on Guava?

Comment: @maaartinus - I have my own non-Guava Multimap class with specialized features. Looking to use with Gson without having to add Guava as a dependency.

Comment: @GRosenberg I see. There's a `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken` but it has no `where` method. These stuff is pretty ugly and I'm afraid, your best bet is to copy the needed Guava classes and remove what you don't need.